# When were ъ and ь first distinguished in Slavic?

Tags: slavic-languages

**Some background info**. These two symbols don't have a reading on their own, but rather affect the sound that appears right before them. In modern Russian they are:

- **ъ**, which is the [**hard sign**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yer#Original_use).
- **ь**, which is instead the **[soft sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_sign)**.

The distinction covers front-vowels and back-vowels (just like in most Fenno-Ugric languages). It also gave a consonant shift (just like in some Fenno-Ugric languages). Some languages spoken at the Slavic language area are Fenno-Ugric.

Can this be a result of Fenno-Ugric influence?

Answer (score 8):

Ь and ъ were alway distinguished in Protoslavic, long before Slavs came into contact with Uralic peoples. The reduced vowel ь developed from the PIE short *ĭ, the reduced vowel ъ developed from the PIE short *ŭ, Old Church Slavonic `вьдова`, Russian `вдова`, Old Indo-Aryan `vidhavā`, Latvian `vĭdua`. Old Church Slavonic `дъва`, Russian `два`, Old Indo-Aryan `dŭva`, Greek `δύω ['düō]`. Also, ъ developed from the PIE *ŭ < *ŏ at the end of the words: Old Church Slavonic `сънъ`, Russian `сон`, Greek `ὕπνος ['hüpnos]`: *sŭpnŏs > *sŭpnŭs > сънъ, `*pn` simplified into `n`, final `s` disappeared according to the rule of open syllables.

Comment: In the word for son there was u always: PIE seuo̯nus. Anyway, +1

Comment: The point bears emphasising that these symbols represented vowels - short vowels, it is true, but fully-fledged vowels (as ъ still does in Bulgarian). Russian has lost the vowels, but retained the palatalisation which went with the vowels (in a similar way to Germanic languages having often lost the following front-vowel that cause umlaut)

Comment: Well, when did (proto)Slavs come into contact with Uralic people then?

Answer (score 2):

These "symbols" were separate vowels long ago. Now they have dropped out in speech, but the effects they had on preceding consonants remain.